# SeleniumGrid: How many instances should I run on single machine

Tags: selenium-grid, selenium-grid2

I have windows 7, 2 processors 64 bit, 8 GB Ram (I have six such nodes)

I am planning to open 15-20 browsers on one machine. Can someone please tell me how many instance of a browsers should I open in one node? Nothing else is running apart from OS and selenium grid node.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to determine total number of instances that should be allowed to run per a single machine, is to do a test run to find out how much resources are used up per instance. You should consider the factors like memory and CPU usage, the type of browsers used, total number of CPU threads/CPUs. The last time I checked most application using a bit of javascript can go as high as 300MB for a single execution in the browser. You ahould also consider the resource utilized by the Selnium Grid as well.

Answer (score 0):

Though this answer is late, I think this might help a few

You have,
6 nodes of 2 CPUs => 6 X 2 = 12 CPUs / processors

1 CPU can only process 1 task at a time. So, the simple answer here is that you can effectively have only 1 active browser instance per cpu. Anything more than that will only result in context switching which is very expensive and not actual parallelization.

You might also want to consider what your target test actually does. Say, if it waits on other micro services that takes time to complete, you might want to have more browser instances and sessions in your node.

Doing a trial and error and plotting a graph should help you arrive at a better solution.